# How to connect snappy-data server with Apache zeppelin for %snappy.sql query support

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin, snappydata

I am currently working on snappy-data sql query functionality,Snappy-data support for Apache zeppelin ,We can do all the functionality using Apache zeppelin connecting to the snappy-data , Then i configured all the setup as per the snappy-data documentation snappy-data with zeppelin [link](https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/zeppelin-interpreter) but after finishing this i can run the using spark interpreter with snappy data Scala programming,at the same time i can't able to run the job on using snappy-data interpreter, its through on "org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException" even i checked my logs also same error only appear on the log file. could you tell me  anyone knows what was the issue on it. if know anything about the issue please share me, Thanks advanced.

Comment: Are you using zeppelin-0.7?Snappydata zeppelin interpreter currently supports zeppelin 0.6.Can you please try with zeppelin 0.6